# Is there any faster way to perform group by row counts using two table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the total number of outlets(nation_id wise) that exist in the orders table in a given date range.

````
select  o2.nation_id,count(o2.id) as outlet_count
    from  outlets o2
    where  o2.id in (
        SELECT  distinct o.outlet_id
            from  orders o
            where  order_date >= '2022-05-01 00:00:00'
              and  order_date <= '2022-06-30 23:59:59'
                    )
    group by  o2.nation_id ```
````

Now, this query gives the exact result but it takes around 3 seconds. Is there any way to perform this query faster? Probably less than 1 second.
N.B.: Outlets table contains around 25k data and orders table contains around 1.2M rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding `IN` will boost the performance and creating indices for nation_id & id columns in outlets table and outlet_id column of orders table will definitely improve the speed.

```
select  o2.nation_id,  count(Ord.outlet_id) as outlet_count
from  outlets o2
LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT  distinct o.outlet_id
        from  orders o
        where  order_date >= '2022-05-01 00:00:00'
          and  order_date <= '2022-06-30 23:59:59'
    ) Ord ON o2.id = Ord.outlet_id
group by  o2.nation_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ananth. I have already created indexs for those columns. And I have tried your query and its pretty faster than my one but still its taking more than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It's something tricky that I just invented and tested (on different tables):

```
SELECT  ou.nation_id, COUNT(*) AS outlet_count
    FROM ( SELECT o.outlet_id, MIN(order_date)
               FROM orders AS o
               WHERE o.order_date >= '2022-05-01'
                 AND o.order_date  < '2022-05-01' + INTERVAL 2 MONTH
               GROUP BY o.outlet_id
         ) AS olist
    JOIN outlets AS ou  ON ou.id = olist.outlet_id
    GROUP BY ou.nation_id
```

The `GROUP BY` *together* with the `MIN` (or `MAX`, etc) is a trick to get the Optimizer to hop through the index, touching only one row per `outlet_id`.  Leaving out the `MIN` or changing to `DISTINCT` failed to involve the optimization.  (Caveat:  Different versions of MySQL/MariaDB may work differently here.)

```
orders:  INDEX(outlet_id, order_date)  -- required for the trick
```

If there are any issues, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`